# How to append content to input element?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm just learning jQuery and I've been able to get the following code working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <h1></h1>
  </header>
  <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
Text Field Populated With XML Value.</br>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
      </br></br>
Dropdown Populated With XML Data.</br>
      <select id="cdLDAP">
        <option/>
      </select>
  </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // variables declaration
    var XML_PATH = "XML/ou.xml";   
    // load XML file
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          $(xml).find('LDAP').find('OU').each(function(i) {
            var ou = $(this).text();
            $('#cdLDAP').append("<option class='ddheader'>"+ou+"</option>");
          });
          $(this).find('Name').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).text();
            $('#cdLDAP').append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ name +"'>"+name+"</option>");
          });
        }
      });
    });    
  </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

This works great; it is able to read the following XML:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DropDown>
    <LDAP>
        <OU>1</OU>
        <OU>2</OU>
        <OU>3</OU>
        <OU>4</OU>
        <OU>5</OU>
        <OU>6</OU>
        <OU>7</OU>
    </LDAP>
</DropDown>
```

And it displays the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in the dropdown `cdLDAP` with no problems.

So far so good.

The problem I'm having is populating a simple text file...in this case:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
```

Say I just want the first value from the xml file, namely the "1" from:

```
        <OU>1</OU>
```

to be displayed in the text field on the HTML5 form.  How do I do that?  Nothing I've tried seems to work.  I think I'm getting confused with the `.each` part, as in `.each(function(i)` and also what to put for

```
$('#text1').append(
```

Answer (score 1):

Input elements behave slightly differently from other HTML elements. Instead of trying to insert the value into its HTML, you need to modify the `value` property of the element.

This can be accomplished using jQuery:

```
$('#text1').val(...)
```

or just plain old DOM property reassignment:

```
$('#text1')[0].value = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to set the `value` of `#text1` to the first `OU` value then you could use the `.index()` method to determine which `:eq` is present. Just remember that `.index()` is `0 based values` so we would be looking for `$('OU:eq(0)')`:

```
$(xml).find('LDAP').find('OU').each(function(i) {
    var ou = $(this).text();
    if($(this).index()==0){
        $('#text1').val(ou)
    }
    $('#cdLDAP').append("<option class='ddheader'>"+ou+"</option>");
});
```

or you could use:

```
success: function(xml) {
    $('#text1').val( $(xml).find('LDAP').find('OU:eq(0)').text() )
    // rest of code
}
```